# Google Docs Thumbnails link missing on upload without conversion

Tags: google-docs-api

I have been using the Gdocs API to upload images without conversion.  In the response, I used to see a thumbnail entry under feed.entry.link[x].  This appears to be missing since 2 days ago.  Does anyone know if a change has been made to the API?  Is there an alternate method of getting the thumbnail URL of an uploaded file?

Thanks!
Roderick Forsythe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any change to the API, the thumbnail should still be available as the link with rel="http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007/thumbnail".

Can you show us your request and the response which doesn't include the thumbnail link?

EDIT: It takes a short amount of time before the thumbnail gets generated and you might not get it in the response of the creation request. It will show up if you GET the resource after you create it.

Comment: Hi Claudio, here is the resulting XML:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:docs='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' gd:etag='&quot;WV4bFxlLHyt7ImBk&quot;'>
<id>https://docs.google.com/feeds/id/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU</id>
<published>2012-04-12T14:45:45.161Z</published>
<updated>2012-04-12T14:45:45.161Z</updated>
<app:edited xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app'>2012-04-12T14:45:45.161Z</app:edited>

Comment: <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels#modified-by-me' label='modified-by-me'/>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels#shared' label='shared'/><category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#file' label='image/png'/>
<title>test</title>

Comment: <content type='image/png' src='https://doc-0o-9c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/1p31s4b3e3ml7aic03amkdl9187vrdr4/00op54podfl1131jqvp8g2c12fsnfi73/1334239200000/16518681538899012357/16518681538899012357/0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU?h=01324516909979296490&amp;e=download&amp;gd=true'/>

<link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://docs.google.com/a/whitestratus.com/file/d/0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU/edit'/>

<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#icon' type='image/png' href='https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_image_list.png'/>

Comment: <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#resumable-edit-media' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU'/>

<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#alt-edit-media' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/file/default/private/full/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU'/>

Comment: <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU'/><link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU'/>

<link rel='edit-media' type='image/png' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/media/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU'/><author><name>roderick.forsythe</name>
<gd:resourceId>file:0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU</gd:resourceId>
<docs:modifiedByMeDate>2012-04-12T14:45:44.247Z</docs:modifiedByMeDate>

Comment: <gd:lastModifiedBy><name>roderick.forsythe</name>
<email>roderick.forsythe@whitestratus.com</email>
</gd:lastModifiedBy>
<gd:quotaBytesUsed>58908</gd:quotaBytesUsed><docs:writersCanInvite value='true'/><docs:md5Checksum>7c1c28efdae2ab0bf9e4bcf33425679d</docs:md5Checksum><docs:filename>test</docs:filename><docs:suggestedFilename>test</docs:suggestedFilename><docs:size>58908</docs:size>
<gd:feedLink rel='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessControlList' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU/acl'/>

Comment: <gd:feedLink rel='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessControlList' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU/acl'/>
<gd:feedLink rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007/revisions' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU/revisions'/>
</entry>

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:docs='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' gd:etag='&quot;WV4bFxlLHyt7ImBk&quot;'><id>https://docs.google.com/feeds/id/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU</id><published>2012-04-12T14:45:45.161Z</published><updated>2012-04-12T14:45:45.161Z</updated>
<app:edited xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app'>2012-04-12T14:45:45.161Z</app:edited>

Comment: <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels#modified-by-me' label='modified-by-me'/>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels' term='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005/labels#shared' label='shared'/>
<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#file' label='image/png'/>
<title>test</title>

Comment: <content type='image/png' src='https://doc-0o-9c-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/1p31s4b3e3ml7aic03amkdl9187vrdr4/00op54podfl1131jqvp8g2c12fsnfi73/1334239200000/16518681538899012357/16518681538899012357/0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU?h=01324516909979296490&amp;e=download&amp;gd=true'/>
<link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://docs.google.com/a/whitestratus.com/file/d/0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU/edit'/>

Comment: <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#icon' type='image/png' href='https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_image_list.png'/>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#resumable-edit-media' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/create-session/default/private/full/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU'/>
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007#alt-edit-media' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/upload/file/default/private/full/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU'/>

Comment: <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU'/>
<link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU'/>
<link rel='edit-media' type='image/png' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/media/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU'/>
<author>
<name>roderick.forsythe</name>
<email>roderick.forsythe@whitestratus.com</email>
</author>

Comment: <gd:resourceId>file:0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU</gd:resourceId><docs:modifiedByMeDate>2012-04-12T14:45:44.247Z</docs:modifiedByMeDate>
<gd:lastModifiedBy><name>roderick.forsythe</name><email>roderick.forsythe@whitestratus.com</email></gd:lastModifiedBy>
<gd:quotaBytesUsed>58908</gd:quotaBytesUsed>
<docs:writersCanInvite value='true'/><docs:md5Checksum>7c1c28efdae2ab0bf9e4bcf33425679d</docs:md5Checksum>
<docs:filename>test</docs:filename>
<docs:suggestedFilename>test</docs:suggestedFilename>

Comment: <docs:size>58908</docs:size><gd:feedLink rel='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessControlList' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU/acl'/>
<gd:feedLink rel='http://schemas.google.com/docs/2007/revisions' href='https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/file%3A0B6E-e8vXZOXbRERad2t1RHBqZVU/revisions'/>
</entry>

Comment: It takes a short amount of time before the thumbnail gets generated and you might not get it in the response of the creation request. Does it show up if you GET the resource after you create it?

Comment: Thanks!  I did not realize that there was a possible delay given my initial results.  Performing a GET on the resource reveals the thumbnail link information.